# Error due to version compatibility in running jar file

Tags: java

I have created a jar file using JDK 8.0 and I tried to run the jar file in a system which is having JRE 7.0,  but I am getting an error like this:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>java -jar test.jar  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test : Uns
upported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

What change am I need to make in my jar file creation. So that it will run without version compatibility?

Comment: If you created project in Eclipse then try changing **project facet** `Java` to `1.7` & `compiler version` to `1.7`. Then try to run jar with system having JDK 1.7.

Comment: @OO7 I am using CMD and notepad, no IDEs

Comment: What is target system OS ?

Comment: Target may be start from java 7.0 and can be java 8.0 also

Comment: @androidGenX r u running on the JDK 8? and what is your class path set?

Comment: @Krishna I have created jar on JDK 8 but it should work on JDK 7 and JDK 8. What change should I do? I tried to run my jar file in a system consists of JRE 7, then I got that error

Comment: @androidGenX according to me what i have come across that java 8 have some serval changes in order to make some functions better. its have some changes so that it can not be run in older versions so if so its better practice to install older version and make jar.

Comment: @Krishna javac -source 1.7 foo/Bar.java, is this help?? I tried but not working

Comment: java -classpath 1.7 -jar JavaTesting/Member.jar try this with your jar let me see what is output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63333/discussion-between-androidgenx-and-krishna).

Comment: because u have some other jar file that has to be there into the class path u need to do something like this.. javac -source 1.7 -classpath folder/xxxx.jar  folder/Test.java

Comment: *Starting with JDK 8u20, the javac compiler has been updated to implement the Java SE 7 rules.* Check [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999476)

Comment: @OO7 so you mean when created class file on jdk8 and tried to run on jdk7, it wont work?? right??

Comment: @androidGenX how u bundling files?

Comment: @androidGenX u need to bundle it using commandline means that both jar will be executed into the single jar

Comment: @Krishna if i remove classpath it works??????

Comment: @androidGenX if u remove classpath then u need to add those jars into the jre lib means main java libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-source` option for `javac`. For example:

```
javac -source 1.7 foo/Bar.java
```

In theory you can specify the `source` and `target` options separately, but judging by your comment, it sounds like you can't use Java 8 language features at all when targeting 1.7.

Note that this only covers your own source code. If `xbasej-20091203.jar` was built against Java 8, you'll need to find a version which targets Java 7 instead.

Comment: I tried but I am getting error in compilation like 'javac: target version 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8'

Comment: @androidGenX: Right - sounds like you can't use the Java 8 language features at all when targeting 1.7 then.

Comment: Can you tell how buddy? I tried like this : C:\TIPL\GCST>javac -target 1.7 -classpath lib/xbasej-20091203.jar Example2.java
javac: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8

Comment: @androidGenX: Right, it sounds like you can't use Java 8 language features when targeting 1.7, so just use `-source 1.7`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: 1.8?? can you write here??

Comment: got a wrning: 
C:\TIPL\GCST>javac -source 1.7 -classpath lib/xbasej-20091203.jar Example2.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning

Comment: how can avoid that warning??

Comment: @androidGenX: Searching for that warning gives a large number of hits. Did you check them to see if they helped you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63329/discussion-between-androidgenx-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: Same error as what? You've give two errors so far. Using `-source` really should fix the problem - unless the jar file you're using is *also* built for Java 8. (Will edit answer to specify that.)